# Trying to figure out why GET method in restful web services called twice

Tags: rest, jersey, soapui

I have a simple restful web services (Jersey framework) that handles a get request. I fired a request from soapUI (v4.6.4) that passes Authorization token in the request header. From the log statement in the service end, I noticed that it was called twice. First time base64 encoded token is captured and its value is printed then it got called again printing null value. I am trying to understand why this is happening. I read a few threads about it in the web but I was not able to find a clear answer for this case.

I wonder if the soapUI fires a request twice somehow...

```
@Path("/testservice")
public class MyTestService {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Path("/")
    public String test(@Context HttpHeader headers) {
        String token = headers.getRequestHeader().getFirst("Authorization");
        System.out.println("token: " + token);
        return token;
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Can you try a simple curl request to eliminate jersey as the culprit?

Comment: Executing curl command didn't produce same result. It looks like service end point was called only ONCE.